# authentication on second server

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a webpage with a login and some function based on a userrole.
On a second server I run a chat server with login and userrole too.

- First server is an simple webhosting.
- Second server is a rootserver with full privileges.

Now I like to use the same username, password and userrole for chat privileges.

- My first idea was, to call a php script on first server with username and password and it return the state and userrole. But this is not secure enough.
- Second idea was to open the MySQL-Server but the hosting doesn't allow this.

Or is the only secure waysynch the databases over a cronjob?

How can I manage this secure?

Comment: does the "simple webhosting" allow any scripting/etc. or is it just for static HTML?

Comment: The only thing i found is PHP/PERL and cronjobs but only urlcalls.